# Oracle Apex: Conditional List of values with concat

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, lov

I am trying to build dynamic and conditional LOV on condition taken from the page item. I came across this example ...

```
IF :P123_CHOICE = 'EMP' THEN
  RETURN
  'SELECT ename d, empno r
   FROM emp';
ELSE
  RETURN
  'SELECT dname d, deptno r
   FROM dept';
END IF;
```

However I need something little bit more complicated:

```
IF :P123_CHOICE = 'EMP' THEN
  RETURN
  'SELECT ename||' : '||esurname d, empno r
   FROM emp
   WHERE (admin ='N' or ADMIN = 'Y')
   ';
ELSE
  RETURN

  'SELECT ename||' : '||esurname d, empno r
   FROM emp
   WHERE admin ='N'
   ';
END IF;
```

As a result I get errors:

```
*ORA-06550: line 3, column 21: PL/SQL: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated ORA-06550: line 1, column 13: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored ORA-06550: line 5, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ; ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated*
```

It is clearly formatting issue I cannot solve. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to bypass special characters:

```
IF :P123_CHOICE = 'EMP' THEN
RETURN
      q'[select ... ]';
ELSE
RETURN
      q'[ select ...]';
END IF;
```

[Oracle® Database PL/SQL Language Reference
11g Release 1 (11.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm)

Comment: That's cool, and a great way to keep a character string clean. On the other hand, if you simply want to escape a single quote, then a single quote will do that: `'select ename d, empno r from emp where admin = ''N'''`. Two single quotes = one escaped quote in your character string. It's quite elementary, and you'll bump a lot more on the single quote style than the q function.

Comment: OK, so how would you escape concat from my example? like this  ||'' : ''||